# Uninstalling Installshield msi during WiX msi installation process

Tags: wix, uninstallation, installshield-2010

We have moved from InstallShield LE 2010 to WiX.

Our new WiX installer is able to uninstall previous WiX msi packages, but it does not detect the previous version of our software installed from the IS msi.

What steps should we take to make our WiX msi installer to detect the previous IS installations and uninstall them automatically?

Answer (score 2):

In theory you will just need to make sure that the UpgradeCode on your product tag in wix is the same as the one in your InstallShield installer and the version number is greater in the wix project.

How you get that out of your InstallShield project that I don't know as I've never used InstallShield.

Comment: Maybe orca can be [used](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pusu/archive/2009/06/10/understanding-msi.aspx) to get the upgradecode, otherwise look in the [registry](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hr/vside2008/thread/2bc7ab67-e214-4590-b058-c1bfe79fe8c8).

Answer (score 1):

This helped me to grab the ProductCode and UpgradeCode from the old installer.

[How to find the upgrade code & productCode of an installed application in Win 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063129/how-to-find-the-upgrade-code-productcode-of-an-installed-application-in-win-7)

Although I am finding that InstallShield creates its own registry uninstall information along with Windows Installer information. When you uninstall something using Windows Installer (MSIEXEC) that was installed by InstallShield installer, it only wipes the Windows Installer registry nodes keeping InstallShield nodes intact. This makes the product show up in the Add/Remove Programs (Programs and Features) even though Windows Installer successfully uninstalls it.