# Creating project installer in VS2010 - detecting previous installations of lost installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation

I have a C# project in VS2010 and an installer file for it - but the installer project is lost so I am trying to reproduce it.

On the old installer, it presents the following screen if previously installed.

[image]

How can I make this happen for the new installer as well? I have tried to use the same UpgradeCode (found using the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063129/how-to-find-the-upgrade-code-productcode-of-an-installed-application-in-win-7), but it still does not appear. Even running the same installer twice doesn't show it so I am guessing there is an option somewhere..?

Comment: I dont see any screen

Comment: Oh.. it shows fine here.. anyone got ideas why it wouldn't show?

Answer (score 0):

The installer is a signed executable (or at least a uniquely-identified executable) so Windows knows when the 'same' one is being re-run and can present the 'repair/remove' dialog.

Your new installer, though for the same project, has a different signature - so to Windows, it's completely different to the earlier one and therefore you just get the 'install' dialog.

I'm not an expert on the subject, but in principle you'd have to replicate the signature of the earlier installer in your new one. I don't know if that's possible, but if it is then your new installer will look like the old one to Windows and you'll get the 'repair/remove' options.

Comment: I thought this was the purpose of the UpgradeCode? Also, in this case it should still appear when running the new installer twice - which it doesn't..