# Uninstall software

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-installer, installation

My product has a helper executable to uninstall all related sub-products. I uninstall based on upgrade codes of all sub-products.

First, I fetch the product code from upgrade code using [MsiEnumRelatedProducts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370103%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Then I try to uninstall the product using [MsiConfigureProductEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370071%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

The problem is `MsiConfigureProductEx` is returning error.

> Invoked Function: MsiConfigureProductsEx
>       Return Code: 1605 (0x00000645)
>       Description: This action is only valid for products that are currently installed.

Why is `MsiEnumRelatedProducts` returning a invalid product code ? I searched through the windows registry to see if such product code exists. There isn't any. How to debug the issue ?

Edit: Added minimum code that reproduces issue.

```
// UpgradeCodes is an array having upgrade codes of all modules.

TCHAR lpProductCode[GUID_STR_LENGTH];
const TCHAR tszNoReboot[] = _T("REMOVE=ALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress DISABLE_REBOOT_PROMPT=1");

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(UpgradeCodes) / sizeof(UpgradeCodes[0]); i++)
{
   tstring tstrUpgradeCode = UpgradeCodes[i];

   DWORD dwIndex = 0;
   size_t status;

   // for each of the upgrade code, get all the products
   do
   {
       status = MsiEnumRelatedProducts(UpgradeCodes[i], 
                                       0, 
                                       dwIndex, 
                                       lpProductCode);
       if (ERROR_SUCCESS == status)
       {
          UINT uiReturn = MsiConfigureProductEx(lpProductCode, 
                                                INSTALLLEVEL_DEFAULT, 
                                                INSTALLSTATE_DEFAULT, 
                                                tszNoReboot);

          if (ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED == uiReturn)
          {
               // prompt for reboot at the end of all modules uninstallation.
          }

          if (ERROR_SUCCESS != uiReturn)
          {
              // log message with return code.

              // Error Code: 1605 is coming from here.
          }
       }
   }while (ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS != status);
}
```

Comment: Please show your actual code.  Are you checking the return value of `MsiEnumRelatedProducts()` for errors before calling `MsiConfigureProductEx()`? What parameters are you passing to `MsiConfigureProductEx()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Added code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I manually uninstalled a child module from Add or Remove programs and then I ran my utility tool. Since then this issue arised. I checked the Upgrade code in Windows registry to see if upgrade code exists for the failed scenario. There is no such upgrade code. So, `MsiEnumRelatedProducts` is not supposed to return any product code. Windows installer is caching this information some where.

Comment: [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370103%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says "this function lists the currently installed and **advertised** products that have the specified UpgradeCode property in their Property table".  So it does return products that aren't installed.  Try calling [`MsiQueryProductState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see what state MSI thinks the products are in.  And don't uninstall any that aren't installed.

Comment: Could you try to read this thread in its entirety (with comments): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583822/wix-installer-rollback-custom-action-for-a-custom-action-sequenced-after-instal/22585654 . It's not impossible that a major upgrade has failed and left two versions of an application registered. I sort of doubt this, but please do read the thread since the problem seems to be important. I will check back later.

Comment: Hi Mahesh - you got the problem solved? Curious what the problem really was, any chance you can write up a summary?

Answer (score 5):

> Some years have passed and I want to add two scipts that can be used
> to export MSI package information:
> [How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569#29937569) - in **section 2**.
>
> Do visit the link above, but here are direct links to the scripts:
> **`1)`** [the html export version](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/MsiHtmlReport-Mini-V4.vbs) and **`2)`** [the simpler text output](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/MsiRetrieveProductCode.vbs).

---

***Disclaimer***: The below information is very "under the hood". Please use API calls whenever you can to access the MSI database. Also remember to run all your MSI testing on virtual machines so you can easily revert to a "clean state". During MSI development strange things can happen.

---

It is possible that a previous uninstall of that product of yours left something registered upon uninstall, and this is causing all the problems. I would try to check with scripts what is registered on the system.

Found good discussions of retrieving product info with VBScript here, a couple of really good scripts - **recommended**. Go to the sites to find the scripts, they format pretty poorly here and clog the answer.

- http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?act=ST&f=26&t=14035
- http://www.dwarfsoft.com/blog/2010/06/22/msi-package-code-fun/

The **Windows Installer database** is mostly located here:

- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\
- The upgrade code section: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\UpgradeCodes

**You must never touch anything in the Windows Installer Database Registry directly.** It's extremely interconnected and easy to corrupt. Only go through the APIs. Note that the GUIDs in the registry are packed, so you won't find the GUIDs from the package in the registry.

- **Packed GUID**:  03B1692A57845354EA63AD602436AB05
- **Regular GUID**: {A2961B30-4875-4535-AE36-DA064263BA50}

Using the VBScripts above and the registry data directly for inspection you should be able to determine what is happening in the Windows Installer database.

Answer (score 2):

I would never work straight in C++ to test this out. Instead I would eliminate some complexity by trying **PowerShell** or **VBScript** to determine what is wrong with the uninstall routine. You can find information on how to use these scripting tools here in [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933). And [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063129/how-to-find-the-upgrade-code-productcode-of-an-installed-application-in-win-7) is another thread.

- It is not quite clear if some of the uninstalls work, and there is
  one that fails or if the uninstall operation fails altogether? That's
  the first question.
- Have you tried **manually uninstalling** all products from **add/remove** to ensure they all uninstall correctly manually? One of the products could trigger an error return code during uninstall that is caught programatically, but is ignored during manual install. Often these can be from Custom Actions placed after **InstallFinalize**. In this case some setup redesign is called for. In the simplest case it would involve disabling error checking for the custom action, but that fix is not good enough in my opinion.
- It is possible that the product is
  installed, but **per-user**. In other words it might be installed only
  for a single user on the machine, and not for the machine (this is controlled by the [**ALLUSERS**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property). I am not sure how this function works if this is the case - it may even report the product as advertised (available for on demand install via a shortcut, but not actually installed). Again, I have not tried this, and uninstall may still work. Just off the top of my head to try and give you some pointers.
- Have you performed any **major upgrades** of existing MSI files as part of the install of your product?

**One further question**: are you running on Windows 8? And are these MSI files generated with WIX or some other tool? There have been some intermittent reports on [problems that appear at least remotely similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303940/windows-installer-this-action-is-only-valid-for-products-that-are-currently-ins).

Comment: Product is correctly uninstalled if run using `Add/Remove` program. I will look at the install/uninstall log to see if there are any warnings. I am using Win 8.1. The installer file is built using `Advanced Installer`. The major concern is about `MsiEnumRelatedProducts` giving product that no longer existed on the system. So, the question boils down to where does the OS store product codes for the corresponding upgrade codes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a package installer (like Microsoft SQL Server), it can install a host of other items during its installation phase.

Later, when you go to uninstall the big package installer, all of the items that installer added to the system should theoretically be removed.

So, try just uninstalling your application, stop, then look to see if the other smaller applications are still on the system.

If they are, then you will need to uninstall these individual applications **first** when your custom uninstall script starts.

I assume you already have a [System.Configuration.Install.Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) class. Follow a set of steps when installing your application (1, 2, 3, etc.), then perform these steps in reverse order when uninstalling your application (3, 2, 1).

Answer (score 2):

Trying a new approach for you. I have located two products that seem to have at least two productcodes registered for their upgrade codes. They are: **MSVC redistributable 2008** and **MSXML 4.0 SP2**. I have written a small C++ test that seems to work ok.

Essentially I think you need to check for **ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS** before the next iteration of the loop so you don't try to uninstall products that are no longer installed.

Here is some <del>**VS2013 code**</del> that should compile out of the box on a fresh install, empty project.

---

**UPDATE**: updated code to use **VS2017** and a minimal console application.

1. Create a new console project: `File => New => Project... =>  Visual C++, Windows Desktop, Windows Console Application`
2. Paste the below code into the main CPP file (replacing whatever is there)
3. Set a breakpoint and build & run (<kbd>F5</kbd>)
4. <kbd>F10</kbd> to step through
5. If "*Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable*" isn't installed, no related product codes will be found.

---

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"

// The below should really be in stdafx.h (precompiled header)
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN // Exclude stuff from Windows.h
#define STRICT
#include <windows.h>
#include <msi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "msi.lib") // To make code link

int main()
{
    UINT i = 0;
    UINT status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    TCHAR productcode[39] = {};

    const TCHAR upgradecode[39] = L"{AA783A14-A7A3-3D33-95F0-9A351D530011}"; //Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable
    //const TCHAR upgradecode[39] = L"{7CE723E3-E56B-432C-9F24-78C0606045A5}"; // MSXML 4.0 SP2 (KB973688)

    do
    {
        // look up (related) product code(s) for specified upgrade code
        status = MsiEnumRelatedProducts(upgradecode, 0, i, productcode);

        if (status == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) // Test here. 259, ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS
        {
            // No more productcodes for specified upgrade code
            MessageBox(NULL, L"No more productcodes", L"Done", MB_OK);

            break;  // exit do-while loop
        }

        i++; // Next product code

        MessageBox(NULL, productcode, L"Product Code:", MB_OK);

    } while (status != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS);

    return 0;
}
```

**There could be erronously registered products** on your system due to **failed major upgrades** or similar advanced error scenarios, so I am not sure if this solves your problem.

Keep in mind that the Windows Installer Database at **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\UpgradeCodes** contains **packed GUIDs**. You can try the VBScript code found in the following link to convert back and forth between packed and regular GUID formats: http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/guid-converter

More info on guid formats here if it is interesting: http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/working-darwin-descriptors

// TEST DATA 2014 (guids in different formats):

```
// UpgradeCode
    // 41A387AA3A7A33D3590FA953D1350011 => {AA783A14-A7A3-3D33-95F0-9A351D530011}
    // 
// ProductCode
    //
    // Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4148
    // CFD2C1F142D260E3CB8B271543DA9F98 => {1F1C2DFC-2D24-3E06-BCB8-725134ADF989}
    //
    // Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.17
    // D20352A90C039D93DBF6126ECE614057 => {9A25302D-30C0-39D9-BD6F-21E6EC160475}


// UpgradeCode
    // 3E327EC7B65EC234F942870C0606545A => {7CE723E3-E56B-432C-9F24-78C0606045A5}
    // 
// ProductCode
    // 
    // MSXML 4.0 SP2 (KB973688)
    // 6E8A266FCD4F2A1409E1C8110F44DBCE => {F662A8E6-F4DC-41A2-901E-8C11F044BDEC}

    // MSXML 4.0 SP2 (KB954430)
    // DDA39468D428E8B4DB27C8D5DC5CA217 => {86493ADD-824D-4B8E-BD72-8C5DCDC52A71}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will try later today and get back to you.