# WIX Installer. Rollback custom action for a custom action sequenced after installFinalize

Tags: wix, custom-action

I have some custom actions in my installer. These are sequenced after InstallFinalize action.

I need to implement rollback for these custom actions.

As Far as i read, I can only implement rollback for custom actions sequenced between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize.

Any way i can do it?

Comment: Just curious - what could it be that needs to happen after InstallFinalize, that also needs to be rolled back?

Comment: these custom actions are performing some registry operations. it's an old written installer so i was avoiding going into changing the sequences.

Comment: I don't know if you can do it. But it sounds like you have the opportunity to execute the boy scout rule. There is a reason why it is called InstallFinalize. Nothing installer-ish should take place after. Maybe showing a text box or something.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, rollback applies only to the transaction part of the installation, which is between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize. That is the install transaction and there is no rollback outside these boundaries. If you do something after InstallFinalize that fails, it's too late - the install is over. As has been said, don't put your CA there if you want rollback.

Comment: True, and worse yet the immediate mode custom actions after InstallFinalize can cause all kinds of runtime errors. They may be skipped via SCCM or similar deployment systems (not sure why - I have seen it), they can trigger major upgrade rollback (returned error code upon completion of CA, and major upgrade is already over, and uninstall of existing product fails leaving two setup versions registered), and if they show GUI elements they can halt the setup after it is essentially complete causing strange errors in cleanup. I am sure there are other possible problems too.

Comment: A final note can be to never enable error checking for an immediate mode custom action after InstallFinalize that does only read-only stuff. I believe this too, could trigger major upgrade problems as described in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Any custom action that changes the system sequenced after InstallFinalize is by definition an error in design**. I would also be careful with custom actions that show messages and inspect the system. They should NOT return error codes at least, or a full rollback of the install might occur - this is particularly unfortunate for major upgrade scenarios (may leave two versions of a product registered, but only one installed).

Custom actions after InstallFinalize always fail in some contex which you cannot predict - often when the package is deployed via deployment system such as SCCM (SMS) or similar. Generally the custom actions after InstallFinalize are skipped or trigger unexpected rollbacks of the entire installation. They will also fail consistently when run without full administrator rights.

What kind of registry operations are you performing? They should be easy to implement in other ways.

Comment: i see quite a few CAs after Finalize, doing not just registry operations but other stuff too on the local system. I agree, as you said, it's by definition an error in design and i would straight away attempt on re-sequencing them. Thanks

Comment: Yes, Custom Actions after [InstallFinalize is not uncommon - even for expensive software packages. They are always errors waiting to happen - and much worse to deal with than you think (unless they are just checking conditions and not making changes to the system).

Immediate mode CAs that try to change the system can cause all kinds of things. Either they are skipped altogether leaving the system unfinished for the software to operate, they trigger rollback of the whole setup during major upgrades, or the CAs halt the setup altogethere making it unable to complete.

Comment: have few questiions. what do you mean by changing the system. does writing something into registry in my own key, qualify as a change to the system? Moreover, i want to deal with a special case here. which is when someone cancels the installation before it gets completed. If i can do a complete rollback of the setup, that also solves my purpose here. Is that possible, considering i have Immediate CAs after installFinalize

Comment: Writing to the registry is certainly changing the system. Please remove all immediate mode custom actions that change the system - they are all errors by definition. It is unclear why it is even possible to insert them. I will add another answer for what I think you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If your immediate mode custom action add registry data, I would remove them all and convert the registry data to be added by the registry table. This table features built-in support for advanced rollback and merging of registry keys and values. I think this is what you are asking.

When you have a product "in the wild" like you seem to have, I would recommend that you run the major upgrade with RemoveExistingProducts early in the InstallExecuteSequence and then install your new version with all immediate mode "change actions" gone. This should provide a smooth upgrade scenario, but makes patching difficult.