# Upgrade without UpgradeCode

Tags: windows-installer

A previous version of my application is missing the UpgradeCode (as I found out by checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063129/how-to-find-the-upgrade-code-productcode-of-an-installed-application-in-win-7)). **Is there any possible way to preform an upgrade without the UpgradeCode?**

Right now when I'm installing the new verison I end up with 2 versions installed.

An idea I have is to make a script that adds the UpgradeCode to the old version and then I'm able to install the new version and have the old one removed. Is that even possible? Or maybe there is a better way do do this.

Just uninstalling the old version and then installing the new one seems to be a good way to go, but my customer refuses to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a patch that adds the UpgradeCode, that's what I would try. You can't just add an UpgradeCode to the old version, although I'm not sure what you're getting at. Altering that MSI won't do anything useful because you can't reinstall it. Altering the cached MSI won't help because there's a lot of data in the registry about the relationships between ProductCodes and UpgradeCodes.