# Possibility/Method of Side by Side or Installation of Multiple verisons(different) of Blue Prism

Tags: installation, blueprism

Following is the scenario that i am currently facing

- Blue Prism Databases

  - Local (SQLExpress)
  - Database Server on Network

The Production code is on Database server and currently using Blue Prism Version 5. To learn about new features of Blue Prism Version 6.6, I want to use the local database.

But AFAIK, Blue Prism doesn't support side-by-side installations of two different versions.

The laptop I am using is company provided and I have to use the same for Version 6.6.

Is there any way to have side-by-side installations of different versions of Blue Prism on a single machine.

FYI, I cannot use any virtualization tool due to security policies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you allude to, this behavior is likely unsupported by the Blue Prism Limited entity. If there's any unexpected or even destructive behaviors resulting from running two different Blue Prism versions side-by-side, it's likely Blue Prism will not be able to help you.

However, there are legitimate rationales for wanting to run two separate versions side by side - the steps you'll need to take will depend on exactly the scenario you're encountering.

---

#### If you have an older version and need to install a *newer* version alongside:

1. Download the desired MSI installer from the [Blue Prism Portal](https://portal.blueprism.com).
2. Perform the installation normally, *except* when reaching the "Destination Folder" screen, choose an alternative installation location for the new version.

   Usually, when I do these side-by-side installations, I tack on the version number I'm installing to the end of the "Blue Prism Automate" folder's name (example below):

   [image: Blue Prism Setup - Destination Folder]
3. Complete the rest of the installation as usual. Once complete, you'll be able to run both versions of Blue Prism simultaneously.

---

#### If you have a newer version and need to install an *older* version alongside, *or* the first method doesn't work (slightly more difficult):

1. Download the desired version's MSI installer from the [Blue Prism Portal](https://portal.blueprism.com).
2. Acquire a copy of Microsoft's Orca utility ([more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/orca-exe)), which is available as part of the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk). You'll need to follow the instructions outlined in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315763/how-to-install-orca-which-windows-sdks-contain-the-orca-msi-editing-tool) very closely to get Orca installed.
3. Open Orca and use it to open the Blue Prism MSI you downloaded in Step 1.
4. Navigate to `Tables > LaunchCondition` and remove the `NOT WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED` condition.
5. Launch the Blue Prism installer you just modified in Orca and run the installation process normally, *except* when reaching the "Destination Folder" screen, choose an alternative installation location for the older version.

   Usually, when I do these side-by-side installations, I tack on the version number I'm installing to the end of the "Blue Prism Automate" folder's name (example below):

   [image: Blue Prism Setup - Destination Folder stage]
6. Complete the remainder of the setup process normally.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't thought about changing the installation path. I may have worked but newer version installer removed the older one. So first approach may need more steps like removing the upgrade code etc from the msi. will try the second approach (installing older version when new version is installed) a little while later. BTW, if it succeeds, it'd be quite a hack :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a second version of Blue Prism on a machine this will work just fine if it's all local however I personally am not a fan of the Orca solution as esqew listed as it involves some technical insight on the MSI setup that I think can trip up people if they're not familiar with BP setups (but is still a valid solution if you want to go that way). I listed my concerns below on multiple BP versions.

Here's the solution I currently have on my local machine for work where I have multiple versions of BluePrism installed and they all work just fine but that is largely because I treat them **independantly**. If you don't want to treat your environments as completely separate then I would advise not going down the route of managing different environments if you can help it and avoid reading on as it's all based on them being independent.

Blue Prism is OK so long as the code you are moving around is moving into later versions that aren't too far apart but if you move Blue Prism code from a later version back to an earlier version you can have a lot of headaches because Blue Prism does not have an XML cleaner (or rather not a very verbose one) so if you introduce code from a later version back into an earlier one it'll either be a complete headache to clean up or will just be easier to make anew. (In my own experience I first encountered this when I pulled something from 6.8 into 6.2 if I recall rightly for a client and broke some MS Edge interaction functions and they were within the same major version so I suspect it only gets worse when they're not the same major version)

So to be clear, in your scenario if you install version 6.6 and work on it to build some new project and then want to move the code you write on 6.6 back to the production Blue Prism that has a version of 5 then that likely won't work and will throw a lot of errors at runtime that will be a pain to fix. This will be **10x worse** if you also then import some code function from 6.6 to 5 that's a common code like 'Utility - Excel' or similar and overwrite the previously working function. There are a lot of other things that could potentially cause headaches, too many to list but the top of my head I believe 6.0 relied on .Net 4.7 which was an upgrade from what version 5 had (which was .Net 4 I think) so potentially you could have clashes on your environment if not set up correctly. I believe the code for how collections were handled was also changed in version 6 onwards so that could cause some issues if not tested thoroughly, also date management changed too and switched to UTC so some new behaviours could be there too.

If, however, you only want to look at version 6+ for yourself out of curiosity and exploration to see how it works with things then the easiest way to do this is just to build another database on whatever server you are connected to, and since you have a local SQL express database you **likely** can do this (you need rights to be able to make a database to do anything else listed below here as that's what I have on my machine).

On my local machine, I have multiple databases and on each database multiple Blue Prism instances

example of one

[image]

I mainly use these when teams send me code to review or run workshops with people for events. In my C drive I have multiple folders for different BP versions (like mentioned above)

[image]

On your local instance you can install as many Blue Prism versions as you like really, they're all technically separate, but when you configure it to look at a database if you point it at a database that already exists with an incompatible version (forward or backwards) it'll tell you in a prompt. You can however just make a new database and go from them. To make a new database just configure connections
[image]

[image]

Make a new connection, then select create database. make sure the database server field is filled in etc. Give the database a new name if you're worried about table clashes, maybe something like Blueprism6.6TEST or something quite clear.

When ready click create and it'll do the script for you automatically. it'll prompt you if you don't have access rights to create the database (again it's local so assume you do)

when done you can login as normal with default username password, then set your license when you login first you'll need the license for it I believe v5 and v6.2+ licenses are incompatible so you can't reuse your first license though you can download BP desktop and use the 30 day license there to get you through for now). Then you can use it like a normal instance. Small word of caution, whatever license you use do not exceed the paid license distribution limits you have are. If it's just for testing and exploring it's not a big deal but if don't go trying to use it for production as you will have all sorts of problems in the future and I'm not endorsing you create multiple databases to skirt licensing in any way to be clear.

[image]

Anyway, once your BP UI points its connections to the right database you won't have any issues in opening and exploring the tool. So long as they're seperate on the database side you can run as many as you like. Again though I will caution, please do avoid trying to write code in one version then importing it to another. If you're using it for testing and exploring it's fine but if you cross the versions you almost certainly will have problems with the code.

If you just want to learn new features on Blue Prism I also advise just going here https://portal.blueprism.com/product/related-products/blue-prism-desktop to download and test the tool as it has something you can download locally if you wanted to on your personal machine to explore the capabilities of the tool. Might be an option if you wanted to avoid any of the multiple installations in parallel juggling headaches if you wanted to avoid them. Just another thought.