# Could not load file or assembly CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp, setup-project, wpf-core

I have a WPF net core project and it's using CEF ChromiumWebBrowser, in the debug mode it run ok. Then I create Setup Project to make file msi file for client but it has error "File 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' of project output 'Publish Items from CommunicateWithWeb (Active)' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'" while building. After I change TargetPlatform of Setup Project to x64, build is successfully.
Then I run msi file to install app in my PC but I can't open this app by clicking exe file. I open event viewer and error is like picture below.

Anyone can help me this problem? I spent 2 days to research but can't solve it. Any comment is also important for me. Thank you.

Note: I use VS2022, CefSharp.WPF.NETCore ver 108.4.130. I also install MS Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64 and x86) ver 14.34.31931

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JnS0.png

Update: I installed Orca and see that CefSharp assembly is already included in .msi file as picture below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Ngj.png

Comment: If you install [Orca](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48315763/16563198) you can use it to look inside the .msi file to check whether it includes the CefSharp assembly - select the "Files" table from the list on the left hand side to see all the files that the .msi file contains.

Comment: @sbridewell Thank you so much. I installed Orca as you suggest and see that CefSharp assembly is already included in .msi file. So do you have any idea about this issuse?

Comment: Asked at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4352